# "SDK directory does not exist" error

Tags: android, windows, react-native, sdk

I'm using React Native for making an android app but when I try to run that app, it stops because it can't find SDK location. My project location is: `E:\UD1\projects\Calculator` and this is the Android SDK location: `D:\AndroidSDK`

I tried adding SDK location to `local.properties` file like this:

```
sdk.dir = D:\AndroidSDK
```

but it didn't work and now I have this strange error:

```
The SDK directory 'E:\UD1\projects\Calculator\android\D:AndroidSDK' does not exist.
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: find where is the sdk in local machine and set it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an escape characters.

This is an example from my `local.properties`:

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\android_sdk
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This trick really worked. I don't know why should I add escape characters.